# How to get the column value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, python-3.7

| Location | Category | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Duliajan Area | PD | 1 |
| Duliajan Area | SE | 3 |
| HAPJAN | COL | 1 |
| HAPJAN | OTH | 1 |
| KATHALGURI | COL | 1 |
| KATHALGURI | DP-PD | 1 |

How can I get count in a variable. (SE - 3),(PD - 1) like that

Comment: What do you mean?  For all rows?

Comment: Yes, I need the value of all 'Category' rows count & same time I need 'Location' 'Category' of count also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use `to_dict`:

```
>>> tuple(df.set_index('Category')['Count'].to_dict().items())
(('PD', 1), ('SE', 3), ('COL', 1), ('OTH', 1), ('DP-PD', 1))
```

If your output must be a tuple and you want to extract one key, you can use:

```
count = tuple(df.set_index('Category')['Count'].to_dict().items())
print(dict(count)['PD'])

# Output
1
```

Comment: How can get the 'Count' only from this tuple ? for example I need the PD count 1

Comment: What you want is not clear. Do you want `df['Count']` only?

Comment: I have used your code its fine. Now I need that count value from that tuple output. For example how can I get PD's count from the tuple.

Comment: Why do you need a `tuple` and not a `dict`? or simply `df.loc[df['Category'] == 'PD', 'Count']`

Comment: Thanks, How can I change the Count type integer into string

Comment: `str(dict(count)['PD'])` or from origin: `df['Count'] = df['Count'].astype(str)`

Answer (score 0):

```
# import pandas library
import pandas as pd

# dictionary
dict = {'Location': ['Duliajan Area', 'Duliajan Area',
            'HAPJAN', 'HAPJAN'],
        'Category': ['PD', 'SE', 
              'COL', 'OTH']
         'Count': [1, 3,
                   1, 1]}

# create a dataframe object
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)

# show the dataframe
print(df)

# list of values of 'category' column
category_list = df['Category'].tolist()

# show the list
print(category_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use pandas library and can use for loop that will loop for the length of column and you can find the lenght by using `.shape` method
To get `(SE - 3),(PD - 1)` format you can use `f"({category_column[i]}-{count_column[i]})"`

So your final code should be:
import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.read_csv("file3.csv")
category_column = df[" Category"]
count_column = df[" Count"]
num_rows = df.shape[0]
new_list = []
for i in range(num_rows):
    new_list.append(f"({category_column[i]}-{count_column[i]})")
```

Comment: Only I need the value not like SE-3 PD-1

Comment: okay, you can change the format by replacing "-"

Comment: And if you only need  'Count' only just use `count_column`